# Laravel: How to update packages in storage/framework

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, octobercms

I have removed a package with `composer remove` and it's now removed from `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files and also removed from `vendor` directory. But I noticed that it's still listed in these two files: `storage/framework/packages.php` and `storage/framework/services.php`. How can I update/rebuild these files?
Also, when I run `php artisan` in the root of my project, I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Class 'Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvider' not found

I searched in all the files of the project and found `JalaliServiceProvider` still listed only in the two above-mentioned files.

Comment: What package did you remove?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan optimize` ?

Comment: @WimPruiksma `Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvide`. Look at the updated question.

Comment: @SanderVisser No. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @SanderVisser Running `php artisan optimize` raises the same error: `Class 'Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: Did you remove the service provider from the `config/app.php`?

Comment: If you want to remove a package with composer just delete the package from composer.json and run composer update

Comment: @AmandoVledder Yes the package is not listed there.

Comment: Also try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: 1. first check are you in the working folder ?

Comment: @AmandoVledder `composer dump-autoload` didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment below line from `config/app.php`

```
   Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvider::class
```

Comment: Indeed, I was loading this class programatically, so I never included it in the `app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your package is registered in config/app.php. remove the package Morilog\Jalali\JalaliServiceProvider::class

Comment: No it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal once

Answer (score -1):

Delete these two files:

`bootstrap/cache/packages.php`

`bootstrap/cache/services.php`

Answer (score -2):

According to this - https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md there is no `post-remove-cmd` event, therefore whatever you have in your `post-update-cmd` or `post-install-cmd` was not executed.

Which suggests it might be the problem with `php artisan optimize`.