# Class not found [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.5`, I want to use `CrondJobs` but none of my classes found in my php file

```
//This Is My Name Space
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Crons;

//Using Jalali but Class Not Found
$date =\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::now()->format("Y/m/d " );
```

This is my error in my error_log

> PHP Fatal error:   Uncaught Error: Class 'Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian' not
>   found  in /home/micacoco/crons/cron.php:29

Comment: `/home/micacoco/crons/cron.php` doesn't look like a it's in the laravel project.

Comment: Have you registered the package in `config/app.php`?  If not, that could help the cause.  Check out this article for more info: [Laravel: How to update packages in storage/framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350272/laravel-how-to-update-packages-in-storage-framework)

Comment: tanks for your answer but my packages are working in my project but my site server when run my laravel php code can not found my Classes ,models , and packages ........

Answer (score 0):

The possible causes of this error can be:

1. Class doesn’t exist
2. The class name case is not the same for example - Jalalian.php and jalalian.php are not the same even when the class name case is the same check to confirm that the 'use' statement has the right letter case.
3. wrong namespace